# execute multiple scripts (subtract results)

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I want to run multiple scripts in parallel.
I am not sure about all the steps that are required.

Script1:

```
a <- c(11,12,13,14)
a
```

Script2:

```
b <- c(1,2,3,4)
b
```

Main script:

```
scripts <- c("Scrip1.R", "Script2.R")

NbCores <- detectCores()-1
cl <- makeCluster(NbCores)

parLapply(cl, scripts, function(script) {
          res <- system(script, wait=FALSE)
           saveRDS(res, "res.rds")})

stopCluster(cl)
```

Now, If I try to load the  rds file it gives me the value 127.

`readRDS("res.rds")` => 127

I want to load the `a` and `b` values because I want to subtract the result of the two scripts, so I want my result to be:

`a-b  = 10,10,10,10`

I am not sure how to define that.

Comment: What is `script` ?

Comment: @denis:Sorry, I updated

Comment: What you probably want is `source` not `system`, but I can't image how you would get `res` as given scripts would create two objects `a` and `b`. Also `system Script1.R` won't work, as it looks command `Script1.R`  in bash. You probably wanted `system("Rscript Script1.R")`